# Finding AVG value in SQL Query after SUM - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average

I have some query which works fine for me:

```
Select Name,sum(number_hours)/8)*100
from 
T1
where name='PERSON_A'
group by name,booked_date
```

Name is always ONE same person which I put in where clause.Result will be:

```
PERSON_A  100
PERSON_A  140
PERSON_A  120
```

This is calculating some daily utilization for workers for each booked date.
Now I want to calculate AVERAGE daily utilization((120+120+100)/3=120)
But when I put

```
Select Name,AVG(sum(number_hours)/8)*100)
FROM
T1
WHERE name='PERSON_A'
group by name,booked_date
```

I am getting error Invalid use of group function. Why? How can I calculate average value after summuryzing values for daily utilization.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a subquery for the sum and calculate the average in the outer query, like in:

```
SELECT Name, AVG (hsum)
FROM
(
    SELECT Name,sum((number_hours)/8)*100 AS hsum
    FROM
    T1
    WHERE name='PERSON_A'
    GROUP BY name,booked_date
) t
```

Comment: @ederbf there will be two syntax errors though. You need to give **table alias for inner table**. And `sum(number_hours)/8)` missing bracket. Not much, but still ;)

Answer (score 2):

I understand you already have accepted the answer. But give this a try too :) No `subquery`. Quite fast too. I added extra `Count of workdates` column for you to see the dates.

### * [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e2d/25)

Sample data table:

```
ID      NAME    HOURS       WORKDATE
100     j       20          December, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000
200     k       10          December, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000
100     j       10          December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
300     l       20          December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
100     j       5           December, 05 2012 00:00:00+0000
300     l       15          December, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000
100     j       10          December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
400     m       20          December, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Query:

```
SELECT Name, ((sum(hours)/8)*100) AS sum
,count(distinct workdate) workdates, ((sum(hours)/8)*100)/count(
  distinct workdate) as avg    
FROM
    works
    WHERE name='j'
    GROUP BY name
;
```

Results:

```
NAME    SUM     WORKDATES   AVG
j       562.5   3           187.5
```

Comment: @stefke Here is another way to do it ;) Check `Explain Plan` as well.